# Sumproduct VBA with Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sumproduct

I know this question has been asked ad nauseum in some form or other, but all of my Googling hasn't led me to a solution.  I want to use Sumproduct in a VBA loop with moving criteria references.  I know that Sumproduct doesn't work the same in VBA as it does in a spreadsheet.  The formula I'm trying to replicate is as follows:

```
=Sumproduct([KNA_Amt]*--([KNA_Dt]=h$25)*--([KNA_Cat]=$b47)*--([KNA_Prgm]=$D$8))
```

and in an worksheet, this would be dragged down 6 lines and across 12 columns.

In VBA, I have the following code, which obviously doesn't work...

```
sub CalcualteSFA()
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long


r = 87: c = 8
For for_col = 1 To 12
Cells(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct([KNA_Amt]*--([KNA_Dt]=Cells(25, c))*--([KNA_Cat]=cells(r,2))*--([KNA_Prgm]=cells(8,4))
r=r+1
next
r=87
c=c+1
next
end sub
```

So I know that the coding doesn't work, but can someone help me by figuring out a code that would?

Thanks so much!

Comment: looks like SUMIFS would do a better job here.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner--I tried Sumifs, but the problem is the Amt data crosses over various columns.  I think Sumifs only likes to refer to one column, correct?  Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple formulas can be assigned at the same time, and the relative (without `$`) row/column references will be auto adjusted :

```
Sub CalcualteSFA()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = [H87:S92]

    r.Formula = "=Sumproduct([KNA_Amt]*--([KNA_Dt]=h$25)*--([KNA_Cat]=$b47)*--([KNA_Prgm]=$D$8))"

    r.Value = r.Value  ' optional to convert the formulas to values

End Sub
```

Comment: @Slai...will this insert the formula into the cell or the value of the formula?  I don't want the formula to show up.

Comment: @Slai--I tried this, and I got an Application-defined or Object-defined error message.

Comment: @AubreyDubberke it will do both - it will first set the formulas, and then set the cells with the result values of the formulas. I am guessing the error is related to the formula, as it is working for me when I tested it with a simple formula. You can try setting the formula manually in `H87` to see if you get any error.

Comment: @Slai--So, I know the formula will work in the cell in the worksheet.  It's function's performance in VBA that I'm struggling with.